# Find $\frac{d}{dx}$ $\left[f^{-1}\right]$ if $f(x) = \sqrt{e^x+1}$

Tags: calculus

I'm reviewing I got a wrong answer here. I used Log differentiation with both sides and got $\frac{e^x\sqrt{e^x+1}}{2(e^x+1)}$ I think $f^{-1}$ has something to do with this.

Comment: Is it $f^{-1}$ or $f^1$? Sorry, the description looks a little confusing.

Comment: Sorry I fixed it thanks for noticing

Answer (score 2):

First find the inverse: switch $y$ and $x$ in $y=\sqrt{e^x+1}$:

$x=\sqrt{e^y+1} \Longleftrightarrow x^2=e^y+1 \Longleftrightarrow x^2-1=e^y \Longleftrightarrow f^{-1}(x)=y=\ln(x^2-1)$

Now differentiate to get: $$\frac{d}{dx}f^{-1}(x)=\frac{2x}{x^2-1}$$